# BIRT: How to remove a dataset parameter programmatically

Tags: java, birt

I want to modify an existing *.rptdesign file and save it under a new name.
The existing file contains a `Data Set` with a template SQL select statement and several DS parameters.
I'd like to use an actual SQL select statement which uses only part of the DS parameters.

However, the following code results in the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.RuntimeException`: *The structure is floating, and its handle is invalid!*
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.StructureHandle.getStringProperty(StructureHandle.java:207)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DataSetParameterHandle.getName(DataSetParameterHandle.java:143)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DataSetHandle$DataSetParametersPropertyHandle.removeParamBindingsFor(DataSetHandle.java:851)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DataSetHandle$DataSetParametersPropertyHandle.removeItems(DataSetHandle.java:694)
```

--

```
    OdaDataSetHandle dsMaster = (OdaDataSetHandle) report.findDataSet("Master");

    HashSet<String> bindVarsUsed = new HashSet<String>();
    ...
    // find out which DS parameters are actually used
    HashSet<String> bindVarsUsed = new HashSet<String>();
    ...
    ArrayList<OdaDataSetParameterHandle> toRemove = new ArrayList<OdaDataSetParameterHandle>();
    for (Iterator iter = dsMaster.parametersIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        OdaDataSetParameterHandle dsPara = (OdaDataSetParameterHandle)iter.next();
        String name = dsPara.getName();
        if (name.startsWith("param_")) {
            String bindVarName = name.substring(6);
            if (!bindVarsUsed.contains(bindVarName)) {
                toRemove.add(dsPara);
            }
        }
    }
    PropertyHandle paramsHandle = dsMaster.getPropertyHandle( OdaDataSetHandle.PARAMETERS_PROP );
    paramsHandle.removeItems(toRemove);
```

What is wrong here?
Has anyone used the DE API to remove parameters from an existing Data Set?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Resolved it by calling 'removeItem' multiple times and also had to re-evaluate parametersIterator everytime.

```
protected void updateDataSetParameters(OdaDataSetHandle dataSetHandle) throws SemanticException {
    int countMatches = StringUtils.countMatches(dataSetHandle.getQueryText(), "?");
    int paramIndex = 0;
    do {
        paramIndex = 0;
        PropertyHandle odaDataSetParameterProp = dataSetHandle.getPropertyHandle(OdaDataSetHandle.PARAMETERS_PROP);   
        Iterator parametersIterator = dataSetHandle.parametersIterator();
        while(parametersIterator.hasNext()) {
            Object next = parametersIterator.next();
            paramIndex++;
            if(paramIndex > countMatches) {
                odaDataSetParameterProp.removeItem(next);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(paramIndex < countMatches) {
            paramIndex++;
            OdaDataSetParameter dataSetParameter = createDataSetParameter(paramIndex);
            odaDataSetParameterProp.addItem(dataSetParameter);
        }
    } while(countMatches != paramIndex);
}

private OdaDataSetParameter createDataSetParameter(int paramIndex) {
    OdaDataSetParameter dataSetParameter = StructureFactory.createOdaDataSetParameter();
    dataSetParameter.setName("param_" + paramIndex);
    dataSetParameter.setDataType(DesignChoiceConstants.PARAM_TYPE_INTEGER);
    dataSetParameter.setNativeDataType(1);
    dataSetParameter.setPosition(paramIndex);
    dataSetParameter.setIsInput(true);
    dataSetParameter.setIsOutput(false);
    dataSetParameter.setExpressionProperty("defaultValue", new Expression("<evaluation script>", ExpressionType.JAVASCRIPT));
    return dataSetParameter;
}
```

Comment: So the main difference is that you re-evaluate ds.parametersIterator() after removing each item whereas my code is using the same iterator for removing more than one parameter?